# Ecto Association with two objects of same class

Tags: elixir, associations, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to define a Game module that should have an associated `Team` linked to `team_a_id` column and another associated `Team` linked to `team_b_id` column (both should match `id` column on teams table).

So far it looks like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Store.Game do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "games" do
    field :date, :utc_datetime
    field :title, :string

    has_many :game_gets, MyApp.Store.GameBet

    belongs_to :team_a, MyApp.Store.Team
    belongs_to :team_b, MyApp.Store.Team

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(game, attrs) do
    game
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :date, :team_a_id, :team_b_id])
    |> validate_required([:title, :date])
  end
end
```

This is the migration file:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateGames do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:games) do
      add :title, :string
      add :date, :utc_datetime
      add :team_a_id, references(:teams, on_delete: :nothing)
      add :team_b_id, references(:teams, on_delete: :nothing)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:games, [:team_a_id])
    create index(:games, [:team_b_id])
    create unique_index(:games, [:title])
  end
end
```

Team module is defined like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Store.Team do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "teams" do
    field :image_src, :string
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(team, attrs) do
    team
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :image_src])
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

Migration file is pretty standard:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateTeams do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:teams) do
      add :name, :string
      add :image_src, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

But up to this point, whenever I try to create an new Game:

```
{:ok, game} =
      attrs
      |> Enum.into(%{
        date: ~U[2022-07-31 15:03:00Z],
        title: "red_devils_vs_bold_guys_21092022",
        team_a_id: team_a.id,
        team_b_id: team_b.id
      })
      |> MyApp.Store.create_game()
```

I get the following error:

```
     ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column "team_a_id" of relation "games" does not exist
     
         query: INSERT INTO "games" ("date","team_a_id","team_b_id","title","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id"
```

**Just in case anyone wonders, "team_a_id" column does exist:*

```
tourney_dev=# SELECT * FROM games;
 id | title | date | team_a_id | team_b_id | inserted_at | updated_at 
----+-------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Have you tried working the relationship the other way?  Instead of a game "belonging to" 2 teams, this would make more sense to me to use a `has_one`, something like: `has_one :team, MyApp.Store.Team, foreign_key: :id, references: :team_a_id`. (untested -- you'd need a field named `:team_a_id` in your schema too)

Comment: seems like the solution is the foreign_key specified. (also havent tested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To formalize my comment into an example, I would rework the definition into one that uses `has_one` instead of `belongs_to`.  Consider something like the following:

```
defmodule MyApp.Store.Team do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "teams" do
    field :image_src, :string
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  # ...
end

defmodule MyApp.Store.Game do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "games" do
    field :date, :utc_datetime
    field :title, :string


    timestamps()
  end

  schema "games" do
    field :date, :utc_datetime
    field :title, :string
    field :team_a_id :integer
    field :team_b_id :integer
    timestamps()

    has_one :team_a, MyApp.Store.Team, foreign_key: :id, references: :team_a_id
    has_one :team_b, MyApp.Store.Team, foreign_key: :id, references: :team_b_id
  end
  # ...
end
```

The above definitions work, e.g. in `iex` I can do the following (verified/tested):

```
# use changesets to insert:

iex> MyApp.Store.Team.changeset(%Foo.Team{}, %{name: "Alpha"}) |> MyApp.Repo.insert()
iex> MyApp.Store.Team.changeset(%Foo.Team{}, %{name: "Beta"}) |> MyApp..Repo.insert()

# Or pass a valid struct to Repo.insert:
iex> %MyApp.Store.Game{title: "Showdown", team_a_id: 1, team_b_id: 2} |> MyApp.Repo.insert()
```

I think you need to show us what your `MyApp.Store.create_game/1` function is doing.

Remember, with `Ecto` (or any database abstraction tool), defining the relations is only useful *when it's actually useful*.  If you're not querying the database using the abstraction, then it can save time to just write regular old SQL queries.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Everett. I tried this and other and variations and even just set `field :team_a_id, :id` without making the association explicit and it seems the problem is Ecto does not recognize `team_a_id` and `team_b_id` as fields of games table. I'm now looking at the definition on the migration file.

Comment: actually it seems to be the Postgres adapter who wouldn't recognize the field

Comment: If you take Ecto out of it, are you confident that your database schemas are defined properly?  I.e. that foreign keys and constraints are properly defined?

Comment: they are what i posted here. Pretty basic at the moment.

Comment: No no, I don't mean your ECTO schemas, I mean your DATABASE table schemas -- are you confident your tables and relations have been defined correctly?  Like have you inspected the output of postgres `\dt` etc?  I just want to be sure that the database is set up correctly before you worry about the abstraction layer.

Comment: I did @Everett. Nothing weird there, just an integer in :team_a_id matching a regular :id column on the other table

Comment: Ok, I can verify that your db migrations appear correct.  I've updated my answer: I've verified that the schema definitions I included do work, and I included an example of interfacing with them in `iex`